# Remote debugging JVM in docker on AWS EB

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visualvm

I have a docker image in which I start `jstatd -p 1099` and then my Java app. I also expose port 1099 in the dockerfile.

I have deployed this docker image to AWS ElasticBeanstalk and I can see from the EB logs that the port is exposed.

```
/var/log/docker-ps.log
-------------------------------------
'docker ps' ran at Fri Jun 17 04:23:02 UTC 2016: 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
d3199a65e216        8b9c53bb10b6        "/app/run.sh"       5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        1099/tcp, 8080/tcp   jolly_carson
```

I would now like to profile the app using VisualVM. How can I find the correct ip to connect to? Attempts to telnet to the app's domain name on port 1099 time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container's port is not bound to the instance's port, which is good because you don't want to expose your debugging interface publicly. The IP address of the container can be found with:

```
$ sudo docker ps
$ sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <container_id>
```

Start an SSH tunnel that tunnels from port 5005 locally to that IP address and port 5005 on the box.

```
$ ssh ec2-user@ec2-54-204-111-222.compute-1.amazonaws.com -L 5005:<ip>:5005 -N
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can configure port forwarding over `iptables`

```
$ sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' stupefied_swartz
172.17.0.2
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5005 -j REDIRECT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5005
```